# Predictions under a GLMER framework

Tags: regression, logistic, prediction, lme4-nlme

I'm currently working on a wildlife research problem where I evaluated animal habitat selection as a function of distance to landscape features/types (e.g., distance to shrub/scrub). I used a logistic regression framework where my response variable is: 0 = random telemetry locations; 1 = used (or animal) locations. I'm essentially modeling non-random habitat selection as a function of used animal locations and their distance to habitat features relative to random locations and their distances generated on the landscape. My mixed-effects model is as follows:

```
results.1<-glmer(R0A1~Season*MP_Scaled+Season*MPHW_Scaled+Season*HW_Scaled+Season*YP_Scaled+Season*AG_Scaled+Season*SS_Scaled+Site+(1|ID),
           data=turkey2nd,family=binomial)
```

Season is a categorical variable (A = fall/winter, B = spring, C = summer) and is interacting with each habitat type to assess differences in selection based on each season. In other words, does distance to mature pine change from fall/winter, spring, and summer? I also included a random effect for animal ID to account for variation among individual animals as some animals have more or less "used locations" compared to others in the data set (see also Gillies et al. 2006). After running the model, I would now like to output predictive probability estimates for each habitat type and season. In other words, what is the predictive probability of use of shrub/scrub stands during the spring season. Obviously, all other variables must be held constant to achieve this goal but I'm struggling to find a way to achieve my goal. I tried the following code based on a series of internet searches:

```
prediction<-predict(results.1,type="response")
```

However, this provides predictions for all my observations in my data set (37,308 rows or probability values). I really need to fix all other variables constant and then predict across a range of distance values for each habitat type (e.g., shrub/scrub) within a specific season (e.g., spring). Additionally, I would like to create predictive graphs to illustrate the probability of selection based on a specified set of distances. Is there an easy way to do this? I wasn't sure if the random effect would influence the probability estimates in anyway either. I would greatly appreciate any insight on this problem.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: @gung is correct about most of this post: it appears to be asking for `R` code.  But it seems the last (implicit) question about the role of the random effect in the estimates is about statistics rather than coding.  If we could focus on that one then this post looks on topic.  (I suspect it has been answered in other threads, though: consider searching our site.)